# What does this symbol in a schematic diagram mean? (wire through circle)

Tags: schematics, symbol

I am looking at the data sheet for the [iC-NZN N-type laser diode driver](http://www.ichaus.de/upload/pdf/NZN_datasheet_D1en.pdf).

[image: iC-NZN-screenshot]

What does the marked symbol stand for?

It appears in a number of places, always marking IO pins.
My guess would have been that it is a current limiter, but then why not just draw a resistor...

Comment: Who provided the diagram? Did they provide a legend? Somewhere?

Comment: I have never seen this symbol on a IC data-sheet before but on circuit before but on circuit diagrams for a PCB it is often used as a net-tie or star-point where to signals are routed separately then joined together at a single point.

Comment: The symbol will normally be used for a current source.

Comment: @solar-mike I posted the link to the datasheet. It is issued by the manufacturer of the IC.

Comment: @Mathias They draw current sources the usual way (see just left of the CIS pin in the image I posted). A current source makes no sense in this context.

Comment: Do they have other Pdf's that cover how they use symbols? The pdf does seem to be comprehensive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, it is only used for connections to power and ground.

I would guess, it is a low inductance connection with multiple wirebonds with the same effect as Litz wire.  This is of great benefit to reduce ringing in pulsed lasers.

It is similar to a shielded signal but without a flat line below the circle.

Comment: Makes sense to me, thanks. Bonus question: why would I prefer to use such a presumably low-L connection to GND *through the IC*, rather than just large trace on the board? I am specifically talking about the RGND pin, not shown in the image I posted.

Comment: The RGND is not used for pulsed laser current so requirements are lower frequency noise and lower DC current over DC return.

Comment: Exactly, that's my point. It seems to me I could do the same, but better, with a separate trace.

Comment: CLDA needs low L connections to LDA and AGND to lower impedance (L/C) and raise resonant frequency ^2 =1/(LC)